# Priority of SQL Query with multiple OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns:
name, surname (name, lastname)

In a query, try the full name (ex.: Steve Jobs), then I divide the words into the variable (in php) and do the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE 
(`nome` REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2') OR 
(`nome` REGEXP '$bt1') OR 
(`sobrenome` REGEXP '$bt1') OR
(`sobrenome` REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2')
```

The problem is that the display of the results are not following the order of queries, then ends up returning:

```
Steve John
John Jobs
Steve Jobs
```

How do I prioritize the query and return in the case **Steve Jobs**?

Comment: I don't think you've explained what you want very well.  You want one result?  if so, your where clause is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
          (SELECT '1' as sb, usuarios.* FROM usuarios WHERE nom` REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2')
UNION ALL (SELECT '2' as sb, usuarios.* FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$bt1')
UNION ALL (SELECT '3' as sb, usuarios.* FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1')
UNION ALL (SELECT '4' as sb, usuarios.* FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2')
ORDER BY sb
```

Comment: I don't understand this part: SELECT 1 as sb,*

And its not work... can you explain how it works?

Comment: try adding quotes around the 1,2,3,4: `'1'` or `"1"`  It basically adds a new column to your result set that you can sort by.  all rows that match on the first query (full name) have a value of `1` in the new sb column and appear in the sorted result set first.  rows that match the last query  have a value of `4`  in the new sb column and appear last in the result set.

Comment: So I need create a new column SB? What I put in SB? And this Code as correct? I'm receiving Syntax error... (Thanks for help!)

Comment: @GtOkAi, try my latest edit.  the query creates a new column on the fly in the query, you don't create a new column in the table.

Comment: Still having Syntax Error... (right syntax to use near '* FROM usuarios WHERE `nome` REGEXP 'gustavo porto')
UNION ALL (SELECT '2' as sb' at line 1). As the column, I understood ... Something new I did not know, thanks!

Comment: Stil... The full error: 

---------------------------
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2')
UNION ALL (SELECT '2' as sb,* FR' at line 1

Comment: I find the error... We can't use sb, *... So I need set the columns that I use, In the cause: 

SELECT '1' as sb, nome,sobrenome

Answer (score 3):

Neither tables not SQL queries have a default order. That's by design. You always have to provide an `ORDER BY` clause if you want a specific order; otherwise, rows are returned in arbitrary order (not even random!).

In your case, if I've understood what you mean:

```
SELECT *
FROM usuarios
WHERE 
    nome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2' OR 
    nome REGEXP '$bt1' OR 
    sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1' OR
    sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2'
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN nome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2' THEN 1
    WHEN nome REGEXP '$bt1' THEN 2
    WHEN sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1' THEN 3
    WHEN sobrenome REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2' THEN 4
END
```

(I've also removed redundant quotes and parenthesis; not an error, just a pet peeve).

Comment: Good script! But not work. With some modifications(Ex.: with 'Rafael Porto' -> $bt1 = Rafael, $bt2 = Porto):

SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE 
nome REGEXP 'rafael porto' OR 
nome REGEXP 'rafael' OR 
sobrenome REGEXP 'rafael' OR 
nome REGEXP 'porto' OR 
sobrenome REGEXP 'porto' OR 
sobrenome REGEXP 'rafael porto' OR 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN nome REGEXP 'rafael porto' THEN 1 
WHEN nome REGEXP 'rafael' and sobrenome REGEXP 'porto' THEN 2 
WHEN sobrenome REGEXP 'porto' THEN 3 
WHEN sobrenome REGEXP 'rafael porto' THEN 4 
WHEN id = 'rafael' OR id = 'porto' THEN 5 
END

The result is the same as my script

Comment: Do you understand what the ORDER BY clause does? If you do, you shouldn't have problems to adapt it to your exact liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add another table row and make that the index for the priority like:

```
SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE  
(`nome` REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2') OR  
(`nome` REGEXP '$bt1') OR  
(`sobrenome` REGEXP '$bt1') OR 
(`sobrenome` REGEXP '$bt1 $bt2') 
ORDER BY `priority` ASC
```

Like that!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT usuarios.*
FROM (
   ( 1 AS column, '$bt1 $bt2' AS pattern, 0 AS priority ) UNION
   ( 1, '$bt1', 1 ) UNION
   ( 2, '$bt1', 2 ) UNION
   ( 2, '$bt1 $bt2', 3 )
) AS items,
INNER JOIN usuarios
ON( ELT(items.column, usuarios.nome, usuarios.sobrenome) REGEXP items.pattern )
ORDER BY items.priority
```